# echo $? returning 0 instead of 1

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
[root@server ~]# bash << eof
> cat adsfasdf
> echo $?
> eof
cat: adsfasdf: No such file or directory
0
```

Could anyone please explain why it is returning exit status 0 instead of 1?

Answer (score 11):

That is because  variable expansion of `$?` is performed *before* the code is passed to `bash` for execution, so the `echo`ed exit code is of the command which was run before  `bash`:

```
bash-4.1$ ( exit 42 )

bash-4.1$ bash <<EOF
cat asdfasdf
echo $?
EOF
cat: asdfasdf: No such file or directory
42
```

Just single quote the [here-document](http://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) delimiter to stop the variable expansion:

```
bash-4.1$ bash <<'EOF'
cat asdfasdf
echo $?
EOF
cat: asdfasdf: No such file or directory
1
```

Comment: But why 69 and not 42???

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, just old habit formed in my early days of programming. That was long before I started reading sci-fi.

Comment: I assume the single quoting makes all of the information piped into bash string literals (no expansion) until it hits the EOF and is executed by bash?  If so, that's awesome, never knew you could do that.

Comment: Yes, @SteelCityHacker, that is what happens. BTW, although I read the `bash` manual a couple of times, I learned the difference made by the single quotes from `perl`'s similar feature.